# My get_posts endpoint returning "raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)" yet endpoint is well defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am creating an app that will allow one to CRUD posts. I'm using sqlalchemy orm. However at my get_posts endpoint, I get raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_) error. I defined my schemas

```
class PostBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content:str
    published: bool = True

#Defines structure of how data should be sent from the frontend
class PostCreate(PostBase):
    pass #helps avoid errors in our class 


#Defines structure of how data should be sent to the user or how a response should be structured
class PostResponse(PostBase):
    id:int
    title:str
    content:str
    published:bool
    created_at:datetime

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True# pydantic's orm_mode tells the pydantinc model to read the data even if it's not a dict
```

My database model

```
class Post(Base):#post model extends base
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True,nullable = False)
    title = Column(String, nullable= False)
    content = Column(String, nullable = False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default="TRUE",nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),nullable = False,server_default=text('now()'))
```

My get_posts endpoint

```
#Gets all posts
@app.get("/posts",response_model = schemas.PostResponse)
def get_posts(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    posts = db.query(models.Post).all()
    return posts
```

I tried removing the response_model and it works but that's not what I want. I'm including the response model so as to define the structure of my responses. So I expect the endpoint to return a structure based on the PostResponse class.

Comment: What is the actual error message you're receiving? What version of Pydantic are you using? (`orm_mode` and the internal `Config` class has been removed in Pydantic v2, you're now supposed to use a `model_config` attribute instead (and `orm_mode` is named `from_attributes`))

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.